# Running cmd.exe command inside localhost IIS Web Server is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, iis, cmd

I'm facing a usual problem in **Asp.Net** (C#).

Is there anybody who knows the complete successful way to run a **cmd.exe** inside **IIS** (**Win 10 Pro x64 v.2004**)? I have tried almost everything suggested (User privileges,Enable 32 Application, AppPools...etc) with code inside my Form.cs (System.Process.Start...etc.) but with no luck. I've also tried using **java procedure in PL SQL** (I'm using **Oracle 9i Oracle database**) with no result for one more time :(

My aim is to have a button in my form just to run **rwrun60.exe** inside **cmd.exe** in order to display a **RDF report (Oracle Reports 6i)** on screen.

Inside **VS2012 Ultimate** the **embedded IIS** works really fine. However when I try this in **localhost IIS Web Server** the result is nothing. The most bizzare thing is that in **Task Manager** after the button push (with the neccessary code) I can see the processes (**cmd.exe, rwrun60.exe**) running but I cannot see the **Live Previewer** on my screen.

Any help or suggestions?
Thnx in advance
Billy P. Ellas- Athens- Greece

Comment: So let me get this straight; you want your code you launch cmd.exe, which will launch rwrun60.exe, which will draw some kind of report on a screen, and you want to do this in a web server, which is a service that doesn’t interact with the desktop, because it’s on a server which might not even have a desktop, or even a screen?

Comment: Is the aim to provide the user with a PDF version of some report? I think you need to look at finding a new route to a solution, because what you’re attempting is not going to be in any way robust in a production environment even if you do manage to hack out something that looks like it’ll work, in dev.. Also note, Reports 6i is 20 years old.. You’ll certainly have an easier time with a more modern software

Comment: Dear Caius ,thnx for your double answer. The major problem is that there is a tone of Oracle 6i reports (with links, sql queries, formula columns etc). As you realize the convertion in Telerik Reports (per example) demands plenty of time. Reports 6i Builder was a very useful and rapid tool and my thought is how I will still be able to use it. The real aim is to guide the user to use the same Report Live Previewer as he always does. I'm changing the user's habits with .Net App at least I would like to have the chance not to change his habits by displaying his Reports in another not familiar way

Comment: A user of a web server doesn’t see the same desktop that the web server does (and web servers mostly don’t have desktops) so it seems meaningless to craft your website so it opens an app on a computer that doesn’t even have a screen, in a data enter somewhere thousands of miles away from a user who is clicking buttons on a website. If you want to get this working you’ll need a desktop app that opens the report for the user, it will have to connect to the web server (signalr perhaps) and then the server can send a message to the app  to open the report on the user’s screen. This is not easy

Comment: Learn the key differences and then you should give up this idea completely, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3